# SSH_CLIENT variable bringing the server's IP instead of the client's IP when connecting via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, logging, connection

I need to monitor the SSH access logs of an Oracle Linux Server 7.9 to determine which machines accessed this server throughout the day. However, the logs display the IP of the server itself instead of the client's IP.

I have already checked the configurations in my sshd file and also the file in ./pam.d/sshd, and they are all correct. My server does not run any reverse proxy or firewall, and there is no script altering my SSH_CLIENT variable.

What can I do to ensure that my SSH_CLIENT variable displays the client's original IP?"